# Bandit B404 security issue with subprocess import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, bandit-python

According to Bandit's documentation, [importing the subprocess module is considered a low security issue (B404)](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blacklists/blacklist_imports.html#b404-import-subprocess). Unfortunately, it does not provide alternatives or explanation why. Thus, I have 2 questions:

1. How could just importing this module be an issue in itself?
2. What alternatives should I use instead? Should I import only a specific function from this library or should I just avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Our team decided to **turn off** the B404 warning, because as you pointed out it is not useful.

We have [B602: subprocess_popen_with_shell_equals_true](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/b602_subprocess_popen_with_shell_equals_true.html?highlight=b602)
and [B603: subprocess_without_shell_equals_true](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/b603_subprocess_without_shell_equals_true.html#b603-subprocess-without-shell-equals-true) both turned on, which are where actual security issues could happen.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the Bandit [blacklist imports documentation](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blacklists/blacklist_imports.html), this is a low severity issue. It is just a heads-up for anyone who is not aware of the potential security issues related to the library.

You can [suppress the warning](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html) by excluding it with `# nosec B404` on the corresponding line, or by changing scan behavior in your Bandit configuration.